# User upgraded to SQL Connector 6.6.5 now gets: Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords

Tags: linux, mysql, sql, connector

I have a dev user who is running queries to bugzilla via .NET code, and after updating his connector gets the error "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords."  I tried recreating the same password again for his user with no luck.  I have several other users that connect and do not want to impact them. Server version:         5.1.67 Source distribution

I had recently migrated from the old server to a new server, New OS and mysql install.  I moved the DBs over using dumps and I added most of the users by using show grants on the old box and copying the output to the new (I am not a mysql guru, obviously).

He is using a username@'%' account if it matters.

CentOS 6.3

Comment: I can successfully log in from other remote machines using the same credentials for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rehashing the user's password with the newer,longer hash value then issuing a flush-hosts to clear the caches.  It worked.  I used the first answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication) for reference.